# PHP проблема реализации многопоточного вызова функции

Tags: php, многопоточность, windows-10, openserver, асинхронность

уважаемые! Прошу вашей помощи! Перебрал и перепробовал уже кучу различных вариантов и совсем потерял надежду на успех... Пишу диплом, создал универсальное программное средство на языке php, с помощью которого можно установить подключение (через ODBC) с любой SQL-ориентированной базой данных и выполнить тест ее производительности (посредством использования показателей теории массового обслуживания) с помощью вызова процедур, сделанных на стороне базы, в различных степенях нагрузки и (!) различным количеством "клиентов", работающих одновременно с базой. Проблема состоит в следующем: реализовано сейчас и все нормально работает, но только якобы в однопользовательском режиме, а мне нужно для моего исследования создать возможность указывать кол-во пользователей, работающих в системе, дабы сымитировать очередь запросов (I/O) к базе и исследовать длину ее, кол-во клиентов, среднее число обслуживания заявки (запроса) и т.д. Я думал решить эту задачу путем использования многопоточности (вызвать всего 1 функцию, которая вызывает необходимую процедуру и возвращает время ее выполнения одновременно множество раз и разбить это на потоки), но перечитав массу информации узнал, что php не предлагает такую возможность из коробки, а опробованные мною способы (pthreads, open_proc(), PHP-FPM оказались не настраиваемыми под Windows/не рабочими через браузер и т.д.)и весьма был опечален... Если я нахожусь на верном выборе варианта решения этой задачи, то прошу подсказать как мне можно это реализовать в моем проекте (всего 1 функцию необходимо одновременно вызвать 10/50/100 раз). Если же есть другой вариант решения этой задачи, с радостью бы его попробовал реализовать! Заранее спасибо! Использую следующий набор инструментов: ОС Windows 10 x64, OpenServer, Apache-PHP-7.

Comment: Запустить скрипт несколько раз, с разных браузеров например. Как бы имитируете что идёт запрос от нескольких пользователей. Либо заливаем скрипт на серв и просим друзей открыть одновременно или пустить "роботов" через сервисы.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev дело говорит. Какой смысл ветвить процесс, если можно запускать его многократно. Сделайте что то типа фронт контроллера, который даст вам возможность указывать количество пользователей и какие то входные настройки и по кнопке будет запускать ваши процессы с нужными вам параметрами для  каждого пользователя.
Можете предварительно оформить  ваш процесс как консольную комманду а из управляющего скрипта запускать его "асинхронно". Вам конечно понадобится чтоб  они как то общались друг с другом, ну через какую редис, например или Sqlite .

Comment: [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php), возможно поможет вам, однако, вернуть результат в мастер процесс невозможно, следовательно придется данные каждого процесса придется писать куда-то, а потом это все суммировать. Так себе идейка, но должно сработать,

Comment: Ребят, спасибо за советы, но мне просто нужно провести исследование путем показателей теории массового обслуживания, а она подразумевает некую очередь из клиентов, которую мне и нужно исследовать ( найти среднюю скорость обработки заявки(запроса) сервером, количество заявок в очереди, длину очереди и т.д.) по этому мне и нужно распаралелить эту функцию, дабы получить необходимую мне информацию.. Последнее действие осталось сделать и я серьезно застрял, помогите идеей, прошу..

Comment: @Serge вы пишете
 `всего 1 функцию необходимо одновременно вызвать 10/50/100 раз`
В чем сложность то ?  Вы же понимаете что вы любой файл можете выполнить как из веб сервера так и из консоли (командной строки, если вам угодно). Если у вас нет внешний данных то вы можете свою функцию запустить из консоли, правильно ? Ну напишите вторую функцию в другом файле где ваша функция будет запущена через консоль сколько угодно вам раз. Т.е. выполните что то типа `exec` в цикле http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php . Если ваша функция "нагрузки" не обменивается данными, то вообще нет проблем.

Comment: сложность в том, что мне не нужно просто выполнить функцию в цикле последовательно сколь угодно раз, а создать некую очередь асинхронного выполнения моей функции(имитация пользователя в системе) и исследовать ее путем использования показателей теории массового обслуживания. Я думаю, что мне нужно разбить выполнение моей функции на потоки и принимать их за отдельного пользователя. Вот только на php из-под Windows не нашел еще способа реализации.. Может подскажешь что-то похожее?

Comment: @Serge я ведь говорю именно об этом. Я не говорю про последовательное выполнение функции, я говорю про запуск фукций параллельно. Считай что твоя функция, которую надо запустить - это exe файл, а ты попросту запускаешь в цикле 1000 экземпляров этих exe файлов, которые работают независимо друг от друга. Так понятнее ? :) Т.е. еще раз: после запуска твоей функции в цикле - мы не ждем результата выполнения, а запускаем новый экземпляр.

Comment: @Serge вот например - второй ответ это именно то о чем я говорю 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876728/execute-php-script-from-php-page-asynchronously-in-windows-system

Comment: @zalex, спасибо за помощь! Я попробовал этот метод и у меня cmd возвращает ошибку: "Не удается найти "0.01456" (а это время выполнения запроса, возвращаемое моей функцией). Проверьте, правильно ли указано имя и повторите попытку." Мне кажется, мы на верном пути) Только вот как это обойти и сделать, чтобы в браузере выводился результат выполнения моей функции?..

Comment: @Serge почему выдает ошибку - надобно разобраться, хорошо бы чтоб не выдавало. По поводу сбора всей статистики, воспользуйтесь  sqlite3 и сделайте так чтобы функция писала в конце время своего выполнения. Т.е. в начале выполнения создайте объект даты и в конце выполнения, соответственно перед окончание работы посмотрите разницы и запишите в базу данных. Можно записать еще какие то сопутствующие данные.

В свою очередь сделайте министраничку со сбором статистики, задача которой будет попросту выдавать из базы данных - данные на экран. Ну и можете туда накрутить чего угодно дополнительно.

Comment: @zalex, я разобрался с ошибкой, переписал чуток пример и все работает. Вот только я вставил счетчики времени в мою функцию(которая выполняет подключение по ODBC к базе и делает запросы) и по результатам видно, что эта новая функция(которая "запускает в цикле 1000 экземпляров этих exe файлов, которые работают независимо друг от друга") вызывает последовательно мою функцию, а не независимо друг от друга( то есть они линейно работают, а не параллельно.

Comment: @Serge ну я давал вам ссылку, правда сам не проверял как в винде запустить процесс асинхронно. В Линуксе это делается добавлением знака &  в конце вызова. В винде , увы, не знаю. Предполагаю что функцией start /b  .  Больше, увы, я вам ничего не подскажу. Все что мог все сказал :)

Comment: @zalex и на том спасибо огромное!)